# what is the equivalent to componentDidMount outside of class element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, initialization, components, materialize

I am trying to make a React component that will take data from an API and generate a number of collapsible FAQ cards. I can get the the questions to map properly on the page, however I cannot seem to get the dropdown behavior to work properly. I am using the materialize framework and have the following code set up:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import M from "materialize-css"
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
  
componentDidMount() {
  const options = {
    onOpenStart: () => {
      console.log("onOpenStart");
    },
    onOpenEnd: () => {
      console.log("onOpenEnd");
    },
    onCloseStart: () => {
      console.log("onCloseStart");
    },
    onCloseEnd: () => {
      console.log("onCloseEnd");
    },
    inDuration: 300,
    outDuration: 200
  };
  M.Collapsible.init(this.Collapsible, options);  
}

const Question = ({question}) => {
       console.log(question)
       const {questionHeader, additionalText} = question.fields
    
  
  return (
    <div className="Question">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12 m6">
          
            <div className="card-content">
              <ul className="collapsible popout" ref={Collapsible => {
                this.Collapsible = Collapsible;
              }}>
                <li>
                  <div className="collapsible-header">{questionHeader}</div>
                  <div className="collapsible-body"><span>{additionalText}</span></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}


export default Question
```

The problem with my current set up is that you cannot use componentDidMount() to initialize the materialize without a class. Is there a way to do this outside of a class component? How can I Initialize the collapsible?

Comment: `componentDidMount` is only a function, surely you could invoke this function in your React component function. You tagged question with `react-hooks` so it seems you are at least aware of them. If you want to call this function as a side-effect when the component mounts then use the `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array so it's called exactly once after the initial render. See [conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

Answer (score 0):

It's the `useEffect` Hook. To use it only when `componentDidMount` use the `[]` at the end.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Your code
}, [])
```

Don't forget to import the `useEffect` Hook:

`import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`

**Notice:**
You can only use the `useEffect` Hook inside a React component function.

You can create a React function component by defining a regular js function with a capitalized name.

```
function ReactFunctionComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Your code
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: I get the error: "useEffect cannot be called at the top level. React hooks must be called in a react function component or a custom react hook function."

Comment: Yes. I wrote it in the notice. You can only use React hooks inside React function component.